# How can I select a row from the DataGridView equals textbox.Text after clicking a button by C# ?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I select a row from the DataGridView equals textbox.Text after clicking a button  by C# ? Is there another solution ?

```
private void btnChk(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()==txtName.Text)
            {
               dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1];

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, although you can do this multiple ways, you'll basically have to scan the rows until you find a match, unless you maintain a data structure (e.g. hash) that associate some text content to a RowIndex.

Comment: Maybe the number of rows is very large and I takes a significant time to find the row everytime. If this is not an issue the OP's code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do

```
private void btnChk(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()==txtName.Text)
        {
           dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Selected = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It also be answer

```
private void btnChk(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString()==txtName.Text)
        {
           dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Selected = true;
        }

    }
}
```